# Lines style from layer of points in QGIS Expression

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, expression, points-to-line

I would like to draw generate a geometry of n-1 polylines from n points in QGIS 3.22 "Field Expressions"

(Sorry, the screenshot is in french)
[image]

What is the formula to enter here to generate the wanted geometry?

I don t want to use a tool to create another layer or convert mine, just have a style of my points layer.

Example:
[image]
There is 3 points in my layer and i want to generate a polylines of 2 lines.

Comment: Hi, my points layer has n points and i would like n-1 lines (link points two by two)

Comment: I would like to generate a polyline geometry from points exactly from all points it exists in my layer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you have no clear definition for a next point and you just want to get the "next feature" (by "technical" feature id), you can use:

```
make_line($geometry,geometry(get_feature_by_id(@layer,$id+1)))
```

Note that this simple attempt wont work if you have features deleted and therefore a gap in your feature id sequence. To overcome this, you can use a ordered array of available ids, like:

```
with_variable('idarray',array_agg($id,order_by:=$id),
 make_line($geometry,
  geometry(
   get_feature_by_id(@layer,
    array_get(@idarray,array_find(@idarray,$id)+1) -- find the index of the current id and get the next one from the array 
   )
  )
 )
)
```

This way you could also use an attribute to determine the next feature:

```
with_variable('idarray',array_agg($id,order_by:="myattribute"),
 make_line($geometry,
  geometry(
   get_feature_by_id(@layer,
    array_get(@idarray,array_find(@idarray,$id)+1) -- find the index of the current id and get the next one from the array 
   )
  )
 )
)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! As it is automatically generated, there is no gaps.